# Two way binding of directive scope doesn't behave as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

In my angularJS app I use a directive. This directive needs to know the value of a variable in the application scope. Because the app scope variable needs to change when the directive updates it and the directive variable needs to change when the app scope variable changes, I used two way binding.
In my directive:

```
scope: {
    "selectedObject": "=selectedobject"
}
```

In my html:

```
<dirname selectedobject="foo"/>
```

and in my controller:

```
$scope.foo = "somevalue";
//$scope.$apply(); Adding this, I get a '$digest already in progress' error
```

Now when I try to read the value of the `selectedObject` in my directive it starts with null instead of "somevalue". However, changes made in the directive scope propagate nicely to the application scope. How can I make sure it works the other way around too? That, if my controller changes the value of foo, this changes propagates to the directive scope?

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you problem may be (a fiddle reproducing it would help), but it *may* be caused by binding directly to a first level expression (i.e. `selectedobject="foo"`). Could you try rearranging the code a bit so that the desired target (`foo`) is within another object and the binding expression is something like `selectedobject="bar.foo"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read following article as I believe you fall into common pitfall and this article will help you understand your problem

http://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2014/04/19/5-angularjs-antipatterns-and-pitfalls/